# Android : Writing own "handler" for hardware keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I own an Asus Transformer (first model) with the US keyboard dock.

However, I'm French, and thus have to interact in French pretty regularly, which does include writing accented letters.

As far as I know, the current workaround for doing that is to basically popup the software keyboard, not very convenient.

One implementation of being able to write accented (and other special letters such as ß) with a traditional QWERTY layout is the one used in Mac OS X. For those who don't know, this is accomplished by pressing alt + a-key-which-usually-makes-a-lot-of-sense (I'm not kidding, they really make sense), that will give you the accent, then the letter which you want to be accented (so alt + e, then e will give you é).

That's the behavior I'd like to implement. However, I don't really find where I'd have to do that.

I looked at the documentation about keyboard devices ( http://source.android.com/tech/input/keyboard-devices.html ) but I don't think that's the right place to do any changes as I don't want to change any keymap or keycodes.

On the other hand, I took a glance at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice (keyboard.java and keyboardview.java in particular) but I have the impression this is more related to software keyboard.

Does anybody have more clues about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems with entering Russian characters on TF101. I'm more used to phonetic layout than to standard one.

I was able to modify Android example application SoftKeyboard to accomplish that. You can find code at https://protronika.dyndns.org/websvn/listing.php?repname=FLEXKBD&path=%2F&sc=0 .

Sorry, code is very raw with many things hardcoded. I started that project very recently. So it is in "just works" state.

Comment: That link now requires a password. Can you please share it on a public site?